# What is DifferenceRoot?

Tags: linear-algebra, wolfram-alpha

In a question I asked earlier today in an effort to simplify the equation on the left below, I was pointed toward Wolfram Alpha.

I got this back:

[image: Equation From Wolfram Alpha]

I honestly have no idea what the right half of this is trying to say. From what I've gathered it has something to do with something called the linear distance equation. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DifferenceRoot is simply a substitute for the solution to a difference equation.

Comment: To clarify it is saying that the LHS is equal to the solution of a difference equation given by the object DifferenceRoot (and some other factors multiplying this). You could try FunctionExpand on the DifferenceRoot object though I suspect you won't have much luck.

Comment: Sorry but could you clarify a bit more? What are you supposed to do with $y[n]$ if you manage to get a closed form for it, plug in the upper summand (in the above case, $\lfloor \frac {q}{2}\rfloor$? Having a similar issue here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%5B+polygamma%280%2C+n+%2B+3%29%5D%2F%28n%2B1%2Fa%29+from+n+%3D+2+to+m